# Closing database connection in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, connection

Can we close all known/unknown connections to database with the code?

I'm using Access database and my application gives the following error: 
"Could not use ''; file already in use. "

I don't know which connection is opened and no closed, so is there a way to close all application's opened connections?

Comment: I think yes, you may be able to do that by accessing the connection pool and iterating through connections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with disposable objects you should use `using` so they will get disposed, and in this case even closed, when leaving the `using` block. Your code should look something like:

```
using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    // Do work here; connection closed on following line.
}
```

Read about [OleDbConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

**UPDATE:** I missed that you were accessing an access database, so updated the code to use `OleDbConnection` instead.